# How can the Friedman Equation produce negative pressure or density?

Tags: general-relativity, pressure, space-expansion, density, cosmological-inflation

As I understand it, the Friendman Equation provides the driving mechanism for Inflation.$$\frac{\ddot a}{a}=-\frac{4\pi G}{3}\left(\rho+\frac{3p}{c^2}\right)$$If $\rho$ or p is negative enough, you get a positive acceleration (i.e. expansion). I've tried reading through several papers and text, but they all regress into this techno-babble that sounds like Alice-In-Wonderland logic.  Could someone explain in terms of known physics how either the density or pressure of the early universe can be negative, especially during a period of hyper-accelerated expansion?

Comment: Negative pressure is just the same thing as tension. If you pull a rope, that rope carries negative pressure. Negative _energy_ on the other hand is quite exotic.

Comment: Negative pressure is when an enclosed area has lower pressure than the area around it.  How does that apply to a homogeneous universe?

Comment: It's the same as energy. Outside of relativity, there is no absolute energy, just areas with higher or lower energy. In relativity, energy is absolute, you don't have to compare it with anything, e.g. see $E = m c^2$. And similarly, pressure is also absolute.

Comment: I don't understand your analogy.  You can't have negative energy unless you're talking about a negative energy *differential*.  Yes, we're talking about absolutes here, we're talking about the absolute pressure of the entire universe shortly after the start of time, so how can the pressure be negative?

Comment: Well, as I said in the first comment, negative pressure isn't even weird in Newtonian mechanics. It's usually called tension. Do you believe tension can't exist?

Comment: In Mukhanov's book: [Physical foundations of Cosmology](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/physical-foundations-of-cosmology/45E9AA7382874E52BA4CC6862C505EAF), in chapter 5 which is about Inflation, more precisely in sections $5.3$ and $5.4$, called respectively "How can gravity become "repulsive"?" and "How to realize the equation of state $p \approx = - \epsilon$ " There is a good treatment and explanation of this. I could copy an answer from there but it would surely far worse than his explanations.

Comment: @knzhou - Take two rockets, tie them together with a rope.  Start the rockets.  Now you've got tension in a rope.  Please relate this 'Sum of Forces' problem to absolute pressure or density the early universe.

Comment: @Run like hell - I've read it.  It's one of the technobabble explanations to which I was referring. Who gave you permission to 'borrow' gravitational energy?  If you understand it, please explain it to me with *known* physics.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I can't explain it to you because as I already told you I can't do a better job than Mukhanov, if I thought I could I would have wrote an answer without telling you read those sections.

Comment: @Runlikehell - Let's just start with borrowing gravitational energy.  Gravitational energy is 'potential' energy.  How do you borrow potential energy?  I know how to convert it to kinetic energy, but I know of no mechanism to 'borrow' it.  How do you pay it back? If you're pushing these theories without understanding them, you're not thinking critically.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I never said I don't understand it, I just said I can't explain it better than an big expert in the field who's also a great teacher.

Answer (score 4):

The Friedmann equation doesn't *produce* negative pressure or energy density; it just tells you that if $\rho+3p$ is negative then $\ddot{a}$ will be positive, so you'll get accelerating expansion of the universe. We observe accelerating expansion of the universe today, and there is also reasonable evidence that cosmic inflation occurred in the early universe. Thus, we have to consider what physical systems are capable of producing negative pressure or energy density.

Negative energy density is considered extremely exotic, but negative pressure not so much. I'll discuss two situations in which you get negative pressure.

The first one, which is used in many inflation models, is a spin-0 (i.e., scalar) field that fills the universe. Such a field can have negative pressure. We know that such fields exist, because the Higgs boson is a quantum of just such a field that fills the universe. However, the spin-0 field usually assumed to be responsible for inflation is not the Higgs field but another spin-0 field that we haven't detected except, apparently, through its cosmological effects.

I don't know how to give a non-techno-babble explanation of why the pressure of a spin-0 field can be negative. The problem is that spin-0 fields aren't like any of the fields that make up things you have everyday experience with. For example, matter is made from spin-1/2 (i.e., spinor) fields interacting via spin-1 (i.e., vector) fields, and electromagnetic radiation is a spin-1 field. Both of these have positive pressure and energy density. But humans have no intuition about what the pressure and energy density of a spin-0 field are, and have to rely on mathematics to work it out.

Consider a spin-0 field with a self-interaction of the form $V(\phi)$. Then the field theory for a spin-0 field says that there are three contributions to its energy density: the first comes from how fast the field changes in time, the second from how fast the field changes in space, and the third from how it interacts with itself. The energy density turns out to be

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\nabla \phi)^2}{a^2} + V(\phi)$$

and the pressure is

$$p=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 - \frac{1}{6}\frac{(\nabla \phi)^2}{a^2} - V(\phi)$$

(A derivation of these formulas can be found at http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/~wrasetm/files/2017S-GRplusScalar.pdf.)

So, assuming $V(\phi)$ is positive-definite, the energy density is always positive, but the pressure can be negative. In a homogeneous and isotropic universe like ours appears to be, the gradient term (the second one) would be zero. If we assume that the field varies slowly enough that its "kinetic" term (one the first one) is small compared with its "potential" term (the third one), then the relationship between pressure and density is

$$p=-\rho.$$

This negative pressure then makes $\rho+3p$ equal to the negative value $-2\rho$, so $\ddot{a} > 0$ and the expansion accelerates.

The second way to get negative pressure is through vacuum energy. Again, humans have no intuition about how vacuum energy works, because it is so tiny in our universe. Math is again the guide. The energy-momentum-stress tensor for the vacuum, if it isn't exactly zero, must be proportional to the metric tensor, because in a vacuum state there are no other tensors available to construct it out of. So

$$T_\text{vacuum}^{\mu\nu}=\Lambda g^{\mu\nu}$$

In terms of components, this looks like the following in flat spacetime:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0    & p & 0 & 0 \\
0    & 0 & p & 0 \\
0    & 0 & 0 & p
\end{pmatrix}
=\Lambda
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
0 & -1 &  0 &  0 \\
0 &  0 & -1 &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and once again we get

$$p=-\rho$$

and accelerating expansion.

So there are at least two mechanisms for getting enough negative pressure to explain accelerating expansion of the early universe and of today's universe.

Comment: +1 for successfully reducing "techno-babble" to something a non-physicist can grapple with!

Comment: What I fail to understand is this: every equation of state is a function of pressure, volume and temperature. That is **f(p,T,V)=0** in one form or another. I can imagine a scenario where the math leads us to the possibility of negative pressure, but, if volume is positive, I can't understand a physical reality where negative pressure doesn't result in negative temperature.

Comment: Yes, having negative pressure with positive temperature is very unintuitive. I think the problem is that you are expecting the ideal gas law $PV=Nk_B T$ to apply to the contents of the universe, but it doesn’t in the case where strange contents like spin-0 fields or vacuum energy dominate. The statistical mechanics of this stuff is different from that of normal matter, and it allows negative pressure along with positive temperature.

Comment: @G.Smith - No, not the Ideal Gas Law, per se, but every Equation of State known to science has the same basic relation: if volume is positive, then the sign of pressure and temperature have to be the same.  Aren't you a little bit worried that you've ventured into the domain of mathematical witchcraft?  Many of these concepts aren't disprovable, which should make you seriously wonder if it's science at all.

Comment: @G.Smith - However, I'm up-voting because you have done the best job yet of making these ideas accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your upvote and your compliment. However, I disagree with your statement that every equation of state known to science has the same sign for pressure and temperature. Physicists agree on how to do quantum field theory at finite temperature, and when they study spin-1/2 and spin-1 fields at finite temperature they get results that can be verified in the lab. I see no reason to believe that the same analysis applied to spin-0 fields with self-interactions, which cannot be verified in the lab, is wrong. (Continued in next comment.)

Comment: At finite temperature, the interaction term $V(\phi)$ becomes a temperature-dependent "effective potential" $V(\phi,T)$. But, for a field whose time-variation is negligible, the relationships $\rho=+V(\phi,T)$, $p=-V(\phi,T)$, and $p=-\rho$ continue to hold. At higher positive temperature, the pressure just gets more negative. We can't observe this in the lab, but we may have observed it cosmologically.

Comment: If you find relying on negative pressure to be intolerable, then you have to decide how else to reconcile General Relativity, which seems to work well; the homogeneity and isotropy of the universe, which we observe; and the acceleration of the universe's expansion, which we observe. Something with negative pressure seems like the most conservative explanation to most physicists. As for it "not being science", I disagree because, with the study of the CMB, cosmology has become a precision science.

Comment: @G.Smith - Where did you get the idea that General Relativity works well? On anything larger than a solar system it fails miserably. In fact, the only way to get GR to agree with observation on cosmological scales is to imagine a source of mass that has failed every attempt at detection, isn't predicted by the Standard Model, would probably decay if it was, and hasn't got a theoretical foundation that's passed a single experimental test. You would be on more solid theoretical ground saying that Jesus bends the light around galaxy clusters than citing Dark Matter as the cause.

Comment: Aha. Since your question was about the Friedmann equation, I assumed that you accepted GR. A discussion of GR’s successes and problems doesn’t fit in comments! (We’re already over the limit and being told to go to Chat.) I suggest that you post a new question such as “Why does anyone think that GR is correct on scales beyond the solar system?”

Comment: @G.Smith - Sure, if I wanted to get fifty down-votes in the space of an hour, that's the way I'd go about it.  Most of the people on this board are religious zealots incapable of critical thinking or objectively examining their assumptions.  But, again, thanks for your answer, better than most.

Answer (score 0):

You could imply a negative pressure from

$\rho + 3P$

Which features in the Friedmann equation under some strict stipulations, but an alternative way is to just consider

$dE = d\rho V + \rho dV$

Which can also feature in a Friedmann equation.

On the RHS doesn't explicitly talk about pressure, it does imply it. This is because it is related the negative pressure,

$dE = d\rho V + \rho dV = -PdV$

And the equation really says, that as a universe expands, the energy of a universe must vary such that the volume changes with it. (No brainer stuff). In fact the whole thing is related to the equation of state:

$P =w\rho$

We can pull a relevant term to the RHS in

$dE = d\rho V + \rho dV = -w\ \rho dV$

To give

$d\rho V = -(1+w)\rho dV$

Which is a standard equation. From it we can also make a standard formula by rearranging

$\frac{d\rho}{\rho}= -(1+w)\frac{dV}{V}$

Which produced differential log terms

$d \log \rho = -(1+w)d\log V$